# Is it allowed to chain invoke method in PHP?

Tags: php, magic-methods, method-chaining

for example, I have following:

```
class A{
  __invoke(){
    // return an instance of class A itself
  }
}
```

so can I do the following?

```
new A()()()()... or (new A())()()()...
```

and what is the explanation here?
suppose PHP version is newer than 5.4

Ok, I may give a little more explanation why I ask:
I was using ganon.php which is an open source html dom parser.
It is using syntax like $html_node('child_tag') to return another child $html_node where $html_node is an object instance of class HTML_NODE. So I was thinking if I could use chaining to do the selection in a nested html dom structure.

Comment: Pet peeve of mine: questions about language syntax that feature snippets with invalid code... ;-P

Comment: Well, either you can or you can't, why don't you try it? That said, consider using a fluent interface instead or applying the builder pattern. These two approaches are a bit more verbose but much clearer, too.

Comment: Just wondering, why would you want to do this?

Comment: Your edit completely changes the sense of the question. If a function or method returns an object, of course you can call methods from that object. Why couldn't you? That has nothing to do with `__invoke()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that the behaviour you describe actually works, even in PHP/7:

```php
class A{
    public function __invoke($arg){
        echo __METHOD__ . "($arg) called" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a(0);
$a(1)(2)(3);
```

```
A::__invoke(0) called
A::__invoke(1) called
Fatal error: Function name must be a string
```

([demo](https://3v4l.org/6YlOq))

You're probably confused by the [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) feature. If `foo()` returns a 'bar' string, then `foo()()` equals `bar()`:

```php
class A{
    public function __invoke(){
        return 'hello';
    }
}

function hello($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name!" . PHP_EOL;
}

$a = new A();
$a()('Jim');
```

```
Hello, Jim!
```

([demo](https://3v4l.org/NubEA))

You can chain that as long as your functions return more strings with valid function names, but neither `__invoke` nor classes play any relevant role:

```
function one() {
    return 'two';
}

function two() {
    return 'three';
}

function three() {
    return 'four';
}

function four() {
    echo 'Done!';
}

$a = one()()()();
```

```
Done!
```

([demo](https://3v4l.org/2UCpv))

Note: all code snippets above require PHP/7 but they could be emulated with earlier versions just using the appropriate parenthesis and intermediate variables.

---

**Update based on UlrichEckhardt's comment:** I overlooked the *return an instance of class A itself* comment. If you actually do so, code *does* work:

```
class A{
    public function __invoke($arg){
        echo __METHOD__ . "($arg) called" . PHP_EOL;
        return $this;
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a(0);
$a(1)(2)(3);
```

```
class A{
    public function __invoke($arg){
        echo __METHOD__ . "($arg) called" . PHP_EOL;
        return $this;
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a(0);
$a(1)(2)(3);
```

([demo](https://3v4l.org/37dhb))

Of course, this is PHP/7 syntax. For older versions, you need auxiliary variables that break the magic:

```
$a = new A();
$b = $a(1);
$c = $b(2);
$d = $c(3);
$d(4);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you `return $this;` in your initial attempt? Otherwise the returned value is `null` and of course you can't call `null`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt As I understood the (original) question he doesn't want `foo()->bar()` but `foo()()`. But I think he actually wants something entirely different and `__invoke()` is actually irrelevant here.

Comment: I'm not sure about the original question. However, your first `class A` doesn't prove that `$a(0)(1);` doesn't work, because `__invoke()` should have returned `$this` (or something else that can be called). Whether that's what coolgod wanted or not doesn't matter. BTW: Attempting with PHP 5.4, `$a(0)(1);` gives me " PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in php shell code".

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - Your comment made me wonder if I understood the question in the first place. I've just updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

For PHP versions `7.0.0 - 7.0.4` you can use it like as

```
class A{
  public function __invoke($x){
    return __FUNCTION__."$x";
  }
}

echo (new A())(2);
```

**Output:**

```
__invoke2
```